# Django Two apps are sharing their templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-apps

In my django project there has 6 apps installed. Among them 2 of them are sharing their templates.

While creating app 1 view and rendering with app 2 templates it first searching whether there any `.html` template on app 1 template folder if not then it's bringing it from app 2. Same goes for app 2.

But if trying with other applications templates folder's `.html` file it's showing `TemplateDoesNotExist`.

How it possible that 2 app are sharing their template while I haven't written any code for this ???

Comment: What is the template path? If you have `templates/home.html` in two apps, that's basically 1 template. You might want to look at app directories in your template & static paths; `templates/app1/home.html` and `templates/app2/home.html`

Comment: The path was app/template/home.html         I think i got the solution. as all of my 6 apps was not registered in settings.py file so all of there templates was not sharing their templates. Now while i registered all of them in settings.py i find all of them sharing each other templates

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your apps are custom apps (not installed via pip, source exists in project folder), all of the directories that you mentioned in the [`TEMPLATES` configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#configuration), viz. `DIRS` and `APP_DIRS` option are accessible to **all** your apps (based on correct naming / relativeness / heirarchy).

It could also be that you have 2 different templates for your 2 different apps, but if the directory structure is incorrect, you may end up with 1 of them not being accessible, thus technically **sharing** the template between the apps, similar to what [markwalker_ mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792220/django-two-apps-are-sharing-their-templates/45792382#comment78542414_45792220).

Comment: I think i got the solution. as all of my 6 apps was not registered in settings.py file  so all of there templates was not sharing their templates. Now while i registered all of them in settings.py i find all of them sharing each other templates